# create a scheduler for asp.net web application.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application in asp.net 3.5 which is hosted in dedicated server environment.

now i have a pages in my website which goes to facebook,google and get some data and stores in DB. the problem is you have to visit the page to get the data. one of my friend told me that i could create a Windows Service which can do this job for me. I dont want to create a windows service as i only want a page to run in night(once a day) to retrieve the data, stores it into DB and send some emails to management guys.

Please suggest me how can i achieve this. I have searched online with no LUCK.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The authors of Stackoverflow used a solution based on adding an item to the cache, then running their scheduled code when the cache item expired and ran a callback method.

Here is their implementation: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

**Edit**: When it says "at startup", this means in your Global.asax file, in an event called Application_Start.

Comment: I have gone through that page. BUt i dont know where to add my custom method in that which runs my code..

Comment: That post is from 2008. Six months later they abandonded the technique, as Jeff Attwood mentions in a comment dated Feb 2009